# Предотвратить закрытие страницы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, веб-программирование

Ищу способ перехватить событие закрытие вкладки. У меня имеется редактор графики, реализованный в веб - представлении, и я хочу при случайном/намеренном закрытии вкладки/браузера перехватывать это событие, чтобы показывать табличку. Для табличек использую JQuary dialog, но это, судя по всему, совсем не важно. Нашёл вариант с перехватом события следующим образом:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    return "Message"; // в старых версиях хрома можно было вернуть строку, и она показывалась бы в системной табличке как сообщение. 
    //Теперь это сообщение игнорируется, и чтобы перехватить закрытие страницы, данное событие должно вернуть не null/undefined
}
```

Этот способ плох по двум причинам:

1. Это работает не везде. Mozilla игнорирует это событие, в Safari не тестировал. А вот Enge, Chrome, Yandex, Dragon, IceDragon, IE(и Опера тоже скорее всего) поддерживают это событие.
2. Я не могу ничего сделать с этими табличками, не поменять стиль, ни задать текст, ничего вообще.

Вопрос: есть какой-нибудь вариант перехватывать событие закрытия(кроссбраузерный) и выполнять при этом свой код? Тогда я смогу выдать свою табличку. Ах да, главное, чтобы была возможность отмены события. Большое спасибо.

Comment: Для Mozilla видимо нужен `e.preventDefault()`, у меня работает. Но выполнять свой код и полностью предотвратить событие - скорее нельзя. Иначе можно было бы издеваться над пользователями, не давая закрывать страничку.

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg, да, это сработало и у меня. Проверил горячие клавиши - тоже не работают, наверное придется это добавить и в отлов:) Спасибо за подсказку.